# Use constant for Ember computed property dependent key

Tags: javascript, ember.js

For an Ember app, is it possible to use a constant as part of a computed property key ?

So, essentially, I have a constant as below;

```
MY_SECTION {
MY_FIELD: "my-field-id"
}
```

What I want is a computed property on "my-field-id" i.e.

```
myCP: function() {
console.log('Inside CP...');
}.property('section.field.my-field-id.value')
```

However, I want to be able to use constant for my-field-id instead of using it directly. Is that possible ?

Comment: You are using an outdated syntax to define a computed property. That might confuse readers. You should upgrade your question with current syntax which is `myCP: computed('section.field.myfield-id.value', function() {})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola @testndtv, thanks for your question! Yes it is entirely possible to use a constant in the key for a computed property, but to make use of it you will need to use the more modern syntax that @jelhan was mentioning because `.poperty()` is deprecated.

Here is a working example of a controller that I have tested locally and is working as you would expect:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { defineProperty, computed } from '@ember/object';

const PROPERTY_ID = 'some-random-string-that-is-too-long-to-write';

export default Controller.extend({
  // this is just for the example so we can show the value in the template
  // it is not needed to get this to work
  PROPERTY_ID: PROPERTY_ID,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    defineProperty(this, 'myCP', computed(PROPERTY_ID, function() {
      return this.get(PROPERTY_ID);
    }));
  },

  actions: {
    addOne() {
      // this is just for the example to stop the result always being NaN because
      // null + 1 = NaN
      let value = this.get(PROPERTY_ID) || 0;
      this.set(PROPERTY_ID, value + 1);
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see we are making use of `defineProperty` which is being imported from '@ember/object'. You can read more about it in the [API documentation](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject/defineProperty)

The key insight here is that you need to define the property dynamically in the `init()` for this Ember object.

The corresponding template for this Controller is as follows:

```html
Property ID is: {{PROPERTY_ID}}

<br>

And the value is: {{get this PROPERTY_ID}}

<br>

<button {{action 'addOne'}}>Add One</button>
```